# Problem with UrlFetchApp.fetch in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, woocommerce-rest-api, urlfetch

I am trying to use the [ImportJSON.gs script](https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON) to import data from my WooCommerce Web site directly into a Google Sheet.  I have enabled the REST API in WooCommerce and am able to enter the URL directly into Chrome and get an accurate JSON response.  The problem I am having is that when using UrlFetchApp.fetch, the data I get back suggests everything in the URL following a ? or & seems to be either truncated or reencoded to something else, but I haven't quite figured out what URL would give this response.

I have created this simple script to test it:

```
function myFunction() {
 
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://kidswonder.net/wp-json/wc-bookings/v1/products/slots?min_date=2023-01-30&max_date=2023-01-31&product_ids=16304");
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
  
}
```

The expected JSON response, which I get by entering the URL directly into a browser is:
{"records":[{"date":"2023-01-30T09:00","duration":30,"available":50,"booked":0,"product_id":16304},{"date":"2023-01-30T09:30","duration":30,"available":47,"booked":3,"product_id":16304},{"date":"2023-01-30T10:00","duration":30,"available":48,"booked":2,"product_id":16304},{"date":"2023-01-30T10:30","duration":30,"available":50,"booked":0,"product_id":16304},{"date":"2023-01-30T11:00","duration":30,"available":50,"booked":0,"product_id":16304},{"date":"2023-01-30T11:30","duration":30,"available":50,"booked":0,"product_id":16304},{"date":"2023-01-30T12:00","duration":30,"available":50,"booked":0,"product_id":16304},{"date":"2023-01-30T12:30","duration":30,"available":50,"booked":0,"product_id":16304},{"date":"2023-01-30T13:00","duration":30,"available":45,"booked":5,"product_id":16304},{"date":"2023-01-30T13:30","duration":30,"available":50,"booked":0,"product_id":16304},{"date":"2023-01-30T14:00","duration":30,"available":50,"booked":0,"product_id":16304},{"date":"2023-01-30T14:30","duration":30,"available":50,"booked":0,"product_id":16304},{"date":"2023-01-30T15:00","duration":30,"available":50,"booked":0,"product_id":16304},{"date":"2023-01-30T15:30","duration":30,"available":50,"booked":0,"product_id":16304}],"count":14}

But the actual response I get, which is the same as if I had  is:

{"records":[{"date":"2023-02-02T09:00","duration":30,"available":1,"booked":0,"product_id":140},{"date":"2023-02-02T10:00","duration":30,"available":1,"booked":0,"product_id":140},{"date":"2023-02-02T14:00","duration":30,"available":1,"booked":0,"product_id":140},{"date":"2023-02-02T15:00","duration":30,"available":1,"booked":0,"product_id":140},{"date":"2023-02-05T17:00","duration":30,"available":1,"booked":0,"product_id":12314},{"date":"2023-02-05T17:00","duration":30,"available":1,"booked":0,"product_id":12312},{"date":"2023-02-06T10:00","duration":30,"available":1,"booked":0,"product_id":103024},{"date":"2023-02-06T10:00","duration":30,"available":1,"booked":0,"product_id":12312},{"date":"2023-02-06T11:00","duration":30,"available":1,"booked":0,"product_id":103024},{"date":"2023-02-06T11:00","duration":30,"available":1,"booked":0,"product_id":12312},{"date":"2023-02-06T12:00","duration":30,"available":1,"booked":0,"product_id":103024},{"date":"2023-02-06T12:00","duration":30,"available":1,"booked":0,"product_id":12312},{"date":"2023-02-06T13:00","duration":30,"available":1,"booked":0,"product_id":103024},{"date":"2023-02-06T13:00","duration":30,"available":1,"booked":0,"product_id":12312},{"date":"2023-02-06T14:00","duration":30,"available":1,"booked":0,"product_id":103024},{"date":"2023-02-06T14:00","duration":30,"available":1,"booked":0,"product_id":12312},{"date":"2023-02-06T15:00","duration":30,"available":1,"booked":0,"product_id":103024},{"date":"2023-02-06T15:00","duration":30,"available":1,"booked":0,"product_id":12312}],"count":18}

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: FWIW, this function looks as though it uses the [WooCommerce Bookings API](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-bookings-api-docs/#introduction). "WooCommerce Bookings is fully integrated with the WordPress REST API. This allows Bookings data to be read using requests in JSON format and using WordPress REST API Authentication methods and standard HTTP verbs which are understood by most HTTP clients."

Comment: Hi. Where did you get this code? Have you looked at the documentation for [WooBookings REST API](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-bookings-api-docs/#authentication-over-https)? Even the API requires the consumer keys, but your  script doesn't include them. Are **you** sure that this is a valid API call, because it doesn't look like one.

Comment: Yes, I have reviewed the Bookings API documentation.  As noted, when I put this URL directly into a browser I get the correct expected response from my Web site.  When using UrlFetchApp.fetch in a script I get the incorrect response, which is data from my Web site, but not the data that was requested.

Comment: I have tested it both with and without the authentication keys and it has the same response in both the browser directly and with the code.